# javascript split without losing first element (not RegEx)

Tags: javascript, split

I have a string containing ones and zeros split by "," and ";".

```
var x = "1,1,0;1,0,0;1,1,1;"; x.split(";");
```

This wil output an array with just two strings: 1,0,0 and 1,1,1.
What I want is to put all of these numbers in a two dimensional array:
1 1 0
1 0 0 
1 1 1 
If there is a smarter way than just split the string, please let me know.
Otherwise, please tell me how to fix the problem above.

Comment: What you say happens does not, in fact, happen.  Your syntax is incorrect anyway; you forgot to quote the string.

Comment: Good grief who would vote this question **up**?!?  The posted code generates a syntax error, for heaven's sake.

Comment: Im sorry, thats because I didn't copy and pasted it. I will correct it. And please dont be to harsh.

Comment: Well I don't mean to be harsh to you :-)  I'm sure you've got a valid question, but it's important to post code that is actually accurate. Otherwise, people will spend time trying to solve the wrong issue.

Comment: what does the title even mean anyway **edit:** as the answer says I think you forgot array indexes are zero-based

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You need to put quotes around your string.
2. Commentors are correct, your array contains all 3 strings. did you forget that array indices start at 0, not 1?
3. x.split does not modify x, it returns an array

You probably want something like this

```
    var str = "1,1,0;1,0,0;1,1,1";
    var arr = str.split(";");

    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i].split(",");
    }
```

and to verify the result

```
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0, len2 = arr[i].length; j < len2; j++)
        {
            document.write(arr[i][j] + " | ");
        }

        document.write("<br>");
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, my first post here didn't went as smothly as I expected. I will try the code, because it looks likes it solves my problem. Tnks!

Comment: You're welcome. Something like declaring a variable intended to be a string without surrounding it in quotes will always provoke the ire of other SO users! Happy posting.

Comment: so this has been bugging me @ajax333221 you edited my post to include that `len=arr.length; i<len` instead of my `i<arr.length` and I don't think that edit at all clarifies or improves the original post. it is an optimization that is neither necessary, asked for, nor required here.

Answer (score 2):

given the string:

```
  var x = "1,1,0;1,0,0;1,1,1";
```

you can get a two dimensional array of zeros and ones this way:

```
var st = x.split(";")
var twoDimensionalArray = st.map(function(k){
    return k.split(","); 
});
```

of course, thanks to JS method chaining, you can do the whole thing this way:

```
var twoDimTable = x.split(";").map(function(k){
  return k.split(","); 
});
```

the result:

```
 [
   ["1","1","0"],
   ["1","0","0"],
   ["1","1","1"]
 ]
```

well, to get the result as

```
 [
    [1,1,0],
    [1,0,0],
    [1,1,1]
 ]
```

you can do a loop and for each value k within the array do k = +k; 
and you will get numbers instead of strings. However, JavaScript will do the casting
for you when you use these values within an operation with a number.

Comment: in theory, result is `[["1", "1", "0"], ... ]` strings not numbers

Comment: `[["1","1","1 1","1","1 1","0","1 "]]` this is my output, can you explain this? Fixed it :)